# IIf Statement in Access

Tags: ms-access-2013

How do you write and IIF statement searching for multiple fields such as, "not started", "not started-NA", "not started-EOY", and format it to return "yes," if these items are found, and "no" if they are not found in the column?

Comment: Are those the only possible values on the field? I mean this seems like a status field, can this field have more values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Select 
    *, Format([YourField] In ("not started","not started-NA","not started-EOY"), "Yes/No") As Status
From
    tblYourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**SYNTAX**

The syntax for the iif function in MS Access is:

```
iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )
```

Parameters or Arguments

**condition**
The value that you want to test.
**value_if_true**
The value that is returned if condition evaluates to TRUE.
**value_if_false**
The value that is return if condition evaluates to FALSE.

**Example**

```
iif ([Qty] > 10, "large", "small")
```